# Javascript returning NaN where it appears it should be returning a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a column in the database that records the user's work duration as minutes.  I'm trying to get that value, and convert it to HH:mm to total the hours worked per week, but I keep getting stuck.

```
<td><strong>{{ Math.floor(teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser[entry] / 1000 / 60 / 60) + 'h ' + Math.round(teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser[entry] / 1000 / 60 % 60) + 'm' }}</strong></td>
```

I'm terrible at math, so trying to figure out a way to do this with Math libraries only, so I can learn while I'm working on it.  Currently when there is no value, I get a NaN.  What'd I'd like is to see Total: 0h 0m when no value is present.

In the controller:

```
$scope.teamTimeInfoForCurrentWeek = {};

if (data != null) {

    var uniqueNamesArray = [];
    var uniqueHoursWorkedCurrentWeekPerUser = {};

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var newUser = 0;
        data[i].Full_Name = data[i].Employee_Last_Name + ', ' + data[i].Employee_First_Name;

        if (uniqueNamesArray.indexOf(data[i].Full_Name) == -1) {
            uniqueNamesArray.push(data[i].Full_Name);
            newUser = 1;
        }

        if (data[i].Hours_Worked !== null && data[i].Hours_Worked >= 0) {

            data[i].Hours_Worked = moment.duration(data[i].Hours_Worked, 'minutes');
            if (newUser == 1) {
                uniqueHoursWorkedCurrentWeekPerUser[data[i].Full_Name] = moment.duration(data[i].Hours_Worked, 'minutes');
            }
            else {
                uniqueHoursWorkedCurrentWeekPerUser[data[i].Full_Name] += moment.duration(data[i].Hours_Worked, 'minutes');
            }
        }

        if (data[i].Lunch_Duration !== null && data[i].Lunch_Duration >= 0) {
            data[i].Lunch_Duration = moment.duration(data[i].Lunch_Duration, 'minutes');
        }
    }
    $scope.teamTimeInfoForCurrentWeek = data;
    $scope.teamHoursWorkedForCurrentWeek = uniqueHoursWorkedCurrentWeekPerUser;
    $scope.teamNameInfoForCurrentWeek = uniqueNamesArray;
```

I've tried integrating moment, but it seems to have problems working with values that span more than 24 hour when I attempt to create a moment.duration(minuteValue, 'minutes').

Any help is appreciated.  Javascript is just not my cup of tea yet.

Comment: Look on the cases when a value will result as `NaN` at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp . It will give you first place idea of your issue.

Comment: @KamalSingh Ah, that helps.  I really need to put some effort into learning javascript.  I'm terrible at it.

Comment: No problem. Once in a life everything seems terrible. Once understood the crux it gives joy too!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no value is present it is `undefined`. When applying a mathematical operation on something `undefined`, you get a `NaN` (Not-a-Number). So what you want to do is to make sure that any variable that may become `undefined`, would instead result in a `0`, whenever you are applying a math operator. You can use the `||` operator to do this inline.

Like this:

```
Math.floor((teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser[entry] || 0) / 1000 / 60 / 60)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Awesome. If you want to dig deeper into the rabbit hole, I suggest, as a learning experience, you try to separate the above code into an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).

Answer (score 0):

You get `NaN` when you try to use math operators on something that doesn't type coerce into a number. I don't see `teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser` anywhere in your code but I'd guess that `teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser[entry]` is giving back `undefined`. `undefined` divided by anything will give you `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You may default your variables while looping.
see the pattern where if employee first name is missing, I am removing the comma.

Similarly if Hours_Worked is missing, then I am defaulting to 0

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var newUser = 0;
    data[i].Full_Name = (data[i].Employee_Last_Name || '') + (data[i].Employee_First_Name ?  ', ' + data[i].Employee_First_Name : '');
    data[i].Hours_Worked = data[i].Hours_Worked || 0;

    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many cases when a value can result to `NaN` while converting to number. As per documentation below are sample cases where it can evaluate to `NaN` at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

> isNaN(123) //false
>
> isNaN(-1.23) //false
>
> isNaN(5-2) //false
>
> isNaN(0) //false
>
> isNaN('123') //false
>
> isNaN('Hello') //true
>
> isNaN('2005/12/12') //true
>
> isNaN('') //false
>
> isNaN(true) //false
>
> isNaN(undefined) //true
>
> isNaN('NaN') //true
>
> isNaN(NaN) //true
>
> isNaN(0 / 0) //true

You just need to handle your case, before converting to number for value `teamUniqueHoursTotalPerUser[entry]`.